# React, service worker cache

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker

In react I am using the service worker for push notification service, so during a production release without noticing service worker config, it was pushed to live[image] and the site data got cached indefinitely in many of user's browsers.
However now this issue is fixed, but the users who were accessed that specific rollout are still seeing the old version of the site.

Is there any solution for this?